# Importing VQC module from qiskit

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been trying to import VQC (Variational Quantum Circuit) from qiskit library, but that is not available.

Can anyone help me out how to import VQC?

I tried with following codes.

1:

```
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import VQC
```

Output

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[49], line 1
----> 1 from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import VQC

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit.aqua'
```

2:

```
from qiskit_machine_learning.classifiers import VQC
```

Output

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[50], line 1
----> 1 from qiskit_machine_learning.classifiers import VQC

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit_machine_learning'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Install aqua module separately

**pip install qiskit-aqua**

and try it .
Else try this

**from qiskit.aqua import algorithms**

**vqc = algorithms.VQC()**

**rsult = vqc.run()**

Try this

`from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, ParameterVector`

`from qiskit.circuit.library import VQC`

Comment: Thank you. But its is not working.

Comment: 1.  from qiskit.aqua import algorithms  2. ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[32], line 1
----> 1 from qiskit.aqua import algorithms

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit.aqua'

Comment: use qiskit.circuit.library to import VQC . Refer the original answer.

Comment: py -m pip install qiskit-machine-learning